# How can I change bundle ID in the new itunes connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

The new itunes connect (late 2015) no longer has the more button. Where do I go to change my bundle ID. I don't have a binary uploaded yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the tab *App Store*, the first link on the left should be *App information* (sorry, my page is in italian, i'm not sure about the translations), then under *General information* you can change the *Bundle ID* and the *SKU*.
You can't modify them after you uploaded the first build.

Comment: There's a little more to this actually, as I've just found out.  Even if you haven't submitted a build, you still won't be able to change the Bundle Id if you have Game Center switched on.